# Correct scenario for Error Handling React using Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to implement centralized error handling in my application but having issue, as currently i am unable to dispatch functions in my handler. i have multiple slices and made a slice for Error

```
import Service from '../../api/service';

export const fetchAddress = createAsyncThunk('address/fetch', async (data, thunkAPI) => {
  return Service.fetch(getAPIConfig('address')).catch((error) => {
    throw error;
  });
});
```

and in my service i have imported

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

in this file during fetch request i am returning error

```
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios(requestToken)
          .then((response) => {
}.catch(function (error) {
reject(new ApplicationError({ error }));
          });
```

I am getting error for each call and storing it in redux for each call but its now impossible for me to handle error for each call. i am trying to find solution here.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean that it's impossible to handle errors for each call? Why are you unable to dispatch actions from your async action (*thunk*)? What is the issue, more precisely?

Comment: I have multiple slice, and apparently i can't dispatch or call error slice from anyother, that is my understanding - guid me on this as I just dived in this react after having 8 years experience of php and wordpress

Comment: You hace `dispatch` available to you from the `thunkAPI`. https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator